# is intersection of a countable collection of dense, open subsets of a complete metric space also dense in X?

Tags: functional-analysis

i do not know what this site is expecting to write. i've written my question above . saw in a question paper. again writing it.

is intersection of a countable collection of dense, open subsets of a complete metric space also dense in X?

Comment: Yes - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221423/proving-baires-theorem-the-intersection-of-a-sequence-of-dense-open-subsets-of/221434#221434

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this property is called the Baire property, and every complete metric space is a Baire space

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem

Comment: Yes, i checked it immediately after i got this answer and got my problem solved. thank you very much:)