# Proving that the intersection of a sequence of dense open sets in a complete metric space $X$ is non empty

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, cauchy-sequences

Here is what I tried:

Since every set $G_n$ is open and dense, for any point $p$ in $G_1$, there is a neighborhood $N_{r}(p)$ which is completely contained in $G_1$ and contains infinitely many points of $G_n$ for all $n$ since $p$ is a limit point of all $G_n$ and so the intersection must be nonempty. I didn't use the fact that $X$ is complete and this looks too simple overall so there is probably something wrong with this reasoning.

Comment: This is way too naive. Construct a Cauchy sequence that converges to a point in the intersection. This is a careful induction argument. E.g. a related question! (always look there too) is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221423/proving-baires-theorem-the-intersection-of-a-sequence-of-dense-open-subsets-of?rq=1)

Comment: So, $p$ is contained in $G_1$, and you can find plenty of nearby points to $p$ from the other $G_n$, but the question is, how can you be sure that there's a nearby point in *every* $G_n$? Your argument provides no answers to this, and if $X$ is not complete, then this may well be false!

Comment: So I just have to make this more precise? For example, starting from $N_{r_1}(p_1)$ with $p_1$ in $G_1$ I can choose $p_2$ such that $N_{r_2}(p_2)$ is completely contained in the intersection of $G_1$ and $G_2$ which is itself a limit point of $G_3$ and so on. We can make $|p_n - p_m|$ arbitrarily small so that it converges to a point in the intersection of all $G_n$ and I used the fact that $X$ is complete. Does this work?

Comment: @Km356 Yep, that approach should work.

Comment: This is (a version of) the **Baire category theorem**.